Can I discuss my 'symptoms' on the website?
I think I have some psychological troubles ... can I post the symptoms and talk about that in the Cognitive Sciences SE website ??   

No, this is not an appropriate forum. This answer gives several explanations as to why such questions are closed as off-topic. Best of luck finding professional help.
